# Como dar o efeito "modal" numa div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma `div` que é o `progress bar`, e gostaria que essa `div` bloqueasse a interação com as `div` abaixo dela. Basicamente enquanto essa `div progress bar` estivesse aparecendo, não permitisse que fosse possível mexer no que está abaixo dela. Como o efeito do `modal`, que bloqueia tudo que está abaixo dela.

Comment: Já tem algo feito? posta aqui pra darmos uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

Segue esse exemplo abaixo, este site tem outros exemplos de caixa modal https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Modal Example</h2>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma opção. Mas você precisa criar um evento para dar um `displat:none;` na `<div class="overlay">` quando a barra completar.

Eu desabilitei o *Botão Submit* com `tabindex="-1"` para não poder acessa-lo com o <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> mas o ideal seria fazer junto com o JS que remove o *overlay*.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h2 {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 2;
}
.holder {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px; 
    background: aqua; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    color: #000;
    margin: auto;
}
.mask {
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 10; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 0%; 
    background-color: red; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    color: #FFF;
    animation: load 5s linear infinite;
    /* animation-fill-mode: forwards; descomente se quiser que ela pare quando completar  (remova o "infinite" do animation acima)*/
}
@keyframes load {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>100%</h2>
            </div>
            <h2>100%</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div >
    <h1>Título</h1>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e o.
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery para isso

```
function disativa() {
   $("#test *").attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
}
```

Chame esta função quando a barra iniciar